# External APFS container with 3 volumes with different look

Tags: disk-utility, apfs

I have a 2TB external HDD which I have formatted as APFS. I have 3 volumes (MacbookAirOdd, MacbookAirEeven, MacbookAir_Linda) as such:
[image: Container]

[image: Volume 1]

[image: Volume 3]

I thought the 3 volumes were all created the same way. The container shows MacbookAirEven, MacbookAirEeven - Data (volume 1), MacbookAirOdd, MacbookAirOdd - Data (volume 2), and MacbookAir_Linda (volume 3).

I don't know why volumes 1 and 2 have a Data component and volume 3 does not. Volumes 1 and 2 are of "Type:" "APFS Volume Group" and volume 3 has "Type:" "APFS Volume." I have tried adding a 4th volume and it is always added like volume 3. Please explain what is going on here?

Comment: You mention SuperDuper! in a comment. I suspect that 1) the two volume groups were set up by SD as a bootable clone, 2) Linda was set up more recently when bootable clones become more difficult.

Comment: @Gilby that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out with @Gilby's comment. With superduper! to get a cloned bootable system disk you have to erase the disk with diskutil then do an erase copy with SD! I must have done an erase of the volume with no data component and then done a "smart update" (not erase copy) with SD! This just copies what has changed (in this case everything), but only the data and not the system. I now erased with DU and did an erase copy with SD! and it looks just like the other two volumes (ie with data component).

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Volume groups are created when installing newer versions of macOS. Here a volume group contains a volume with the role `System` is which remains mounted read-only while booted to the macOS stored within. There also is a corresponding volume with the role `Data` which contains the part of macOS that is mounted as writeable. The container `disk5`, in the OP's question, appears to contain two macOS installations and thus two volume groups.

Below is an explanation of how to create volume groups. No explanation is given as why a user would wish to manually create one.

---

Prior to macOS Catalina, APFS volume groups did not exist. Each volume in a APFS volume group has been assign a [role](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434637/how-to-know-what-the-different-roles-do-in-diskutil-apfs-shell-command), which is specified when the volume is created or erased. At least with respect to Catalina, one can not add a volume to an APFS container with a specified role by using the Disk Utility. One can by entering one or more commands in a Terminal application window. Below is the example command for adding the volume named `MacbookAir-Alice` to APFS container `disk5`. Here, no volume groups are involved. If a case-sensitive volume is desired, the `apfs` should be replaced with `"case-sensitive apfs"`.

```
diskutil ap addvolume disk5 apfs MacbookAir-Alice
```

Below is an example involving the creation of a new volume group by entering two commands. [Evidently](https://community.jamf.com/t5/jamf-pro/discussion-on-catalina-and-volume-groups/m-p/137021/highlight/true), one must first create a volume whose role is `Data`. The command below creates the volume named `MacbookAir-Bill` in the APFS container `disk5`

```
diskutil ap addvolume disk5 apfs MacbookAir-Bill -role D
```

A new APFS volume group can be created by adding new volume or perhaps erasing an existing volume. The example command below adds a volume named `MacbookAir-Dave` with the role `System` to the APFS container `disk5`, where `MacbookAir-Bill` was created using the previous command. This will create a new APFS volume group containing `MacbookAir-Bill` and `MacbookAir-Dave`.

```
diskutil ap addvolume disk5 apfs MacbookAir-Dave -role S -groupwith MacbookAir-Bill
```

The command below can be used to list all volume groups in container `disk5` along with the roles assigned to the volumes.

```
diskutil ap listvolumegroups disk5
```

Comment: I'm still trying to take that all in. I use this device for backing up 2 MBAs. Odd is for odd weeks and even for even weeks. The Linda is the second MBA. I use SuperDuper! as my backup app. One has a system of Monterey and the other Ventura. Linda is Ventura. The even/odd were setup sometime ago (probably Catalina), Linda more recent. Is the Data designation still in affect, but just lost visibility?

Comment: Whenever using drive related applications and commands in a environment where multiple versions of the operating system exist, the applications and tools from the newest operating system version should be used. To determine where all the containers are you could boot to Ventura and enter the command `diskutil ap listvolumegroups`.

Comment: I found the how to create volume groups very informative. I am wondering how when I created 3 volumes in a container on an external drive using diskutility, two of the volumes created volume groups with a -data component, but the 3rd did not? The only difference that I can think of is the version of MacOS running at creation time was probably different. I'm guessing the 2 volumes that were created as volume groups were added by Catalina and the 3rd volume was added with Ventura.

Comment: I think you are trying to answer your own question. If so, you should post the above comment as an answer. You are allowed to answer your own questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't feel like I've answered it. Catalina creates a volume group and Ventura does not? Is there still a system and data component, but just no longer visible?